# How can I prove $\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} B_iB_{n-i-2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} M_iM_{n-i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recursion, catalan-numbers

I have a recursion $B$ below:

$$\begin{align}
B_{n-1} &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} B_iB_{n-i-2} \\
B_1 &= 1 \\
B_0 &= 1
\end{align}$$

And another $M$ below:

$$\begin{align}
M_n &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} M_iM_{n-i} \\
M_2 &= 1 \\
M_1 &= 1
\end{align}$$

How can I show that these two recursions are equal??

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the number of ways to multiply $n$ matrices"?

Comment: What is a node? A step in the tree an element of a step of the tree?

Comment: @NickPeterson for example if you had four matrices $A, B, C, D$, you can multiply them as $(((AB)C)D), ((A(BC))D), ((AB)(CD))$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just an induction on $n$. Suppose that $M_k=B_{k-1}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n-1$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
M_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}M_kM_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}B_{k-1}B_{n-1-k}\\
&=\;...\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now just shift the indices. I’ve finished it off in the spoiler-protected block below.

> $\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n-2}B_kB_{n-2-k}=B_{n-1}$

Comment: Is there any way you can elaborate?

Comment: @gator: If you include the spoiler, I gave almost the complete proof. Can you tell me what you don’t understand?

Comment: Actually, upon writing it down I see what you mean. I was confused by shifting the indices but now I understand.

Comment: @gator: Ah, good. Index shifts can be a little tricky. One way to handle them safely is by substitution: here we could let $\ell=k-1$, so that as $k$ runs from $1$ to $n-1$, $\ell$ runs from $0$ to $n-2$. Then we get $k=\ell+1$, so that $n-1-k=n-1-(\ell+1)=n-2-\ell$. Once all of the details have been sorted, you can then rename $\ell$ back to $k$ and end up with what I wrote down directly.